# IContextMenu:: QueryContextMenu and the "New" submenu item

Tags: winapi, contextmenu, menuitem, windows-shell

Is it possible to have the "New" submenu (new folder, file ...) included in the menu queried by [IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?.

I didn't find a flag that seems to handle this need. I know that it`s possible to add an own menu but I rather want the shell sub menu.

Thanks,
SKAR

Comment: The "New" submenu is only displayed in the context menu for a folder.  Are you querying the `IContextMenu` of a folder?

Comment: I am using **IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf** to get IContextMenu. Thanks

Comment: I also used **IShellView::GetItemObject** (with SVGIO_BACKGROUND) to get IContextMenu and it's showing "New" menu-item but problem is that it is desktop folder context menu.

Comment: I have managed to get Folder's context menu (same as windows explorer shows for folder when we click in empty region) but issue is the background's context menu shows **Paste** and **Paste shortcut** menu item but grayed while there is an copy entry in clipboard. 


A similar issue has been reported at this [link](http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell.narkive.com/q1VFMetv/q-for-background-context-menu)